# convert table rows to array list in processing

Tags: arraylist, processing

I'm trying to convert a table rows to array list:

```
void setup() {
  Table table = loadTable("country_population.csv", "header");

  ArrayList<TableRow> result = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
  Iterable<TableRow>  rows   = table.rows();
  for(TableRow row : rows) {
    result.add(row);
    // println(row.getString("1960"));
  }

  for(TableRow row : result) {
    println(row.getString("1960"));
  }
}
```

but the second for loop always print the last added row:

[image: see screenshot]

while the commented line in the first loop hasn't any problem!

[image: see screenshot]

and the craziest thing is with the below logic:

```
void setup() {
  Table table = loadTable("country_population.csv", "header");

  ArrayList<TableRow> result = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
  Iterable<TableRow>  rows   = table.rows();
  for(TableRow row : rows) {
    result.add(row);
    println(result.get(0).getString("1960"));
  }
}
```

[image: see screenshot]

what's wrong?!

**NOTE:** used database https://www.kaggle.com/gemartin/world-bank-data-1960-to-2016

Comment: Can you please convert your images to code?

Comment: @Mr.Wrong Done.